# How to create colorbars in ggplot similar to those created by Lattice

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice, colorbar

I want colourbars created with ggplot to be similar to what spplot function (from lattice package) creates. Something like the attached image with each finite number of colours being assigned to rectangular blocks, instead of creating a continuous spectrum of colours. I need to be able to define the outline colour of the colourbar and also the format of the ticks.

[image: An example of what I wish to have]

I put this simple example together. How can I change this into something similar to this attached image? For example, I want the legend to start from -3 and end at 3 with 10 blocks of colours. I already tried 'nbin' in the function 'guides'. But I need the labels to be put at the 'edges' of the colour blocks instead of at the middle of them (i.e. centre of the bins).

ps: And sometimes ggplot creates a labels beyond the length of the colourbar!

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), col=rnorm(100))

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y,color=col)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_gradient2(limits=c(-3,3), midpoint=0) +             
  guides(color=guide_colourbar(nbin=10, raster=FALSE))
```

Comment: I can't get you all the way there, but this gets some of what you want: `guides(color = guide_colourbar(nbin = 10, raster = F, direction = "horizontal", barwidth = 20, barheight = 0.8)) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")`

Answer (score 3):

I think what you ask for is not possible using the latest (public) version of ggplot2.

**Ugly method, do at your own discretion**

However, if you install the development version (this led to some version conflicts with other packages on my machine and I guess some things are not fully working yet) using

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
```

You will get some more options to modify guides such as `ticks.colour`, `frame.colour` or `frame.linewidth` which lets you customize the colorbar according to your requirements:

```
set.seed(6)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100))
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y,color=z)) + geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours=c("blue","gray80","red"), limits=c(-3,3),
    breaks=c(-3/9*8,-3/9*4,0,3/9*4,3/9*8), labels=c(-2.4,-1.2,0,1.2,2.4), na.value = "green",
    guide=guide_colorbar(nbin=10, raster=F, barwidth=20, frame.colour=c("black"),
                         frame.linewidth=1, ticks.colour="black",  direction="horizontal")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

- Use `colours = c()` to specify a vector of colors
- Use `breaks` together with `labels` to manually assign labels at the correct positions along the colorbar. **EDIT:** We can easily compute the required position along the colorbar by dividing 3 (the length of one half along the colorbar) by 9 (there are 9 half-boxes from the middle of the bar to the centre of the first box) and multiplying that by the number of half-boxes where we want the label to appear.
- Values outside of `limits` will be colored according to `na.value`
- You could additionally specify `name = "Your Variable Name"` to replace the `z` next to the colorbar

[image: Colorbar with values between colors and a black contour around bar]

I see no way to put -3 / 3 at the very ends of the color bar, other than manually placing a text element at the correct position in the plot (which I would strongly advice against).

Comment: I don't think this is an ugly solution. It's pretty decent, actually. However, why are the values of the breaks different from the values of the labels?

Comment: Pretty nice method actually. Just, it's very difficult to guess the values of the breaks specially with so many different graphs. I hope the new version is released soon with all the frame and tick options. Cheers.

Comment: @ClausWilke Ugly only because it requires installing the dev branch. Well, that is because ggplot assigns e.g. the value -3 to the centre of the of the first color in the colorbar and not in-between colors (as requested). So we have to calculate which value corresponds to a position in-between colors. Btw. I have figured out a robust way to compute the correct position of the labels using some simple math (see edited response).

Comment: Don't you think when ggplot puts the label of the first box on the right at the middle of it, it means that the label (i.e. 0.6) is the center of the box (i.e. bin), and not its upper boundary, as ggplot calls them bins and not boxes? And do you think the colours follow the same categorization as the legend does (are they not continues)?